# I have to pass an array from a php file to python file but my code is giving output NULL

Tags: php, python

PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = array('1','4','67','34');

$result = shell_exec('C:/Python27/python C:/xampp/htdocs/123.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));

$resultData = json_decode($result, true);

var_dump($resultData);


?>
```

Python Code:

```
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'23','4'}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you target a `.exe` file ?

Comment: Fyi, to pass larger amounts of data using stdin/stdout is much more appropriate than commandline arguments.

Comment: Can you narrow down where the failure is: PHP->Python, or Python->PHP?

Comment: @ThiefMaster can u tell me how to use stdin/stdout plus why it is giving NULL here is my question

Comment: the problem is that data in python script is coming out to be null.. can anyone fix that??

Answer (score 1):

There is incorrect data for `json.dump()` in Python

```
# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'23','4'}
```

So this give error, not json string

```
import sys, json

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'23','4'}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

and PHP get `NULL` as `$result` from Python so you get `NULL` on screen - in browser

Use (for example):

```
# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'a':'23','b':'4'}
```

and `json.dump()` will work fine.

Comment: @MichaelMallett In OP code I found only problem with `json` returned by Python. Python has problem with `json.dump({'23','4'})` so it returns empty string, so PHP gives result NULL (on the screen - in browser). And OP asked for NULL problem. I tested it on computer with Linux Mint, Python 2.7.x, WWW server Apache 2.2.x, PHP 5.3.x. Did you found another explanation ?

Comment: are you using shell_exec() to run the python script in php?  that will return null if there's a problem finding/executing the python script

Answer (score 1):

Add `2>&1` (stdout & stderr) behind the command like so:

```
$result = shell_exec('C:/Python27/python C:/xampp/htdocs/123.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)) . ' 2>&1');
```