# output of json_encode(array) in php

Tags: php, python, json, numpy

PHP:

```
echo json_encode($temp);
$rtu = shell_exec("C:/Python27/python 123.py ".json_encode($temp));
```

Python:

```
import sys, json
import numpy as np
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import array
A=np.matrix(json.loads(sys.argv[1]))
print A
print ("<br/>")
M=A.I
B = np.asarray(M)
print (json.dumps(B.tolist()))
```

I have this array `$temp(29x29)` but when I echo its json_encode my first 28 rows are printed correctly (as in `{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0...`) but the 29th row is printed as `[0,0,0..]`. Moreover the output `$rtu`  is coming out to be null. Can anyone fix that?

Comment: You need to use `escapeshellarg` to keep the special characters in JSON from being processed by the shell.

Comment: The reason 29th row is printed as [0,2,4,3... and so on] is that you have not given index to array containing these values [0,2,4,3... and so on]. Give index 0. ({"0":0,"1":0,"2":0... and so on) Here 0 index ["0":] contains the array.

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425426/i-have-to-pass-an-array-from-a-php-file-to-python-file-but-my-code-is-giving-out

Comment: @Barmar read the whole ques

Comment: Why there is a need of giving index values were assigned to it in a loop in the same way as the other rows

Comment: escapaeshellarg is not adding anything to it.output still same

Comment: Show us `var_dump($temp)`.

Comment: Actually, to keep it manageable, show us `var_dump($temp[0])` and `var_dump($temp[28])`

Comment: for var_dump($temp[0])array(29) { [1]=> int(0) [2]=> float(-5.7570523891767) [3]=> float(-5.0428643469491) [4]=> float(-5.6721497447533) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(0) [9]=> int(0) [10]=> int(0) [11]=> int(0) [12]=> int(0) [13]=> int(0) [14]=> int(0) [15]=> int(0) [16]=> int(0) [17]=> int(0) [18]=> int(0) [19]=> int(0) [20]=> int(0) [21]=> int(0) [22]=> int(0) [23]=> int(0) [24]=> int(0) [25]=> int(0) [26]=> int(0) [27]=> int(0) [28]=> int(0) [0]=> float(33.863370828705) }

Comment: for var_dump($temp[28]): array(29) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(0) [9]=> int(0) [10]=> int(0) [11]=> int(0) [12]=> int(0) [13]=> int(0) [14]=> int(0) [15]=> int(0) [16]=> int(0) [17]=> int(0) [18]=> int(0) [19]=> int(0) [20]=> int(0) [21]=> int(0) [22]=> int(0) [23]=> int(0) [24]=> int(0) [25]=> float(-1.659200265472) [26]=> int(0) [27]=> float(-2.2060445621002) [28]=> float(3.8652448275722) }