# I want to send data from php to python

Tags: php, python

I've tried to send data from php to python, I found a tutorial from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425426/i-have-to-pass-an-array-from-a-php-file-to-python-file-but-my-code-is-giving-out).

this is the code.

php

```
<?php
$data = array('1','4','67','34');
$result = shell_exec('python try.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
$resultData = json_decode($result, true)
var_dump($resultData);
?>
```

python

```
#!/Python27/python
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(data)
```

and output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(67)
  [3]=>
  int(34)
}
```

I try and succeed, but it's just an integer, I want a string.

I tried to replace the data

```
$data = array('tiger','dog','cow','lion');
```

but the result is `NULL`

Comment: A simple `print repr(sys.argv[1])` in Python should show on which side (PHP or Python) the problem lies.

Comment: I'm not sure how python handles escaped args. I would try printing the raw `sys.argv[1]` to see if it's still escaped.

Comment: Also if these are going to be large arrays of data you may want to write it to a temp file and then pass the file path into python.

Comment: If this is on Windows, `escapeshellargs` won't help much; and there's no way for Python to salvage the args. Better use `popen` and pass the JSON per `sys.stdin`.

Comment: works-fine-on-my-end. Missing a semicolon in the php code (syntax error). But yeah definitely don't run a bunch of data through shell arguments, use stdin or a tmpfile. Also specify python2 when executing since python may some day refer to python3 (already does on some os's since several years back) .. and/or use python3 instead (python2 is legacy) ... oh and if I use the wrong python version (causing the shell command to fail), the php result is NULL